# --with prefix in "~$ nginx -V" output

Tags: nginx

In the output of the command "nginx -V" on linux, there's some flags that start with --with, for example "--with-http_gunzip_module". What does this prefix mean? Is that the module is activated or that it's installed?

Comment: I'm a complete newbie in nginx, so take it easy.

Comment: These are the options used to build this executable - so, yes, these modules are built and available. See [this link](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gunzip_module.html) for example.